# PortUnreachableException And SocketException in OrbotVPN

Tags: android, vpn

I used the OrbotVPN library to connect to my VPN server but it shows these error in the logcat:

```
error in tunnel
        java.net.PortUnreachableException: 
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:595)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:565)
        at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.readImpl(DatagramChannelImpl.java:334)
        at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.read(DatagramChannelImpl.java:281)
        at org.torproject.android.vpn.OrbotVpnService$2.run(OrbotVpnService.java:258)
        Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:136)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:159)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:562)
        at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.readImpl(DatagramChannelImpl.java:334) 
        at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.read(DatagramChannelImpl.java:281) 
        at org.torproject.android.vpn.OrbotVpnService$2.run(OrbotVpnService.java:258)
```

And:

```
error in tunnel
            java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:543)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:526)
            at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.writeImpl(DatagramChannelImpl.java:399)
            at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.write(DatagramChannelImpl.java:352)
            at org.torproject.android.vpn.OrbotVpnService$2.run(OrbotVpnService.java:245)
            Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:151)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:169)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:524)
            at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.writeImpl(DatagramChannelImpl.java:399) 
            at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.write(DatagramChannelImpl.java:352) 
            at org.torproject.android.vpn.OrbotVpnService$2.run(OrbotVpnService.java:245)
```

I have set `Server Address` to my server address, Not 127.0.0.1

Also `Server Port` to port I used in

Comment: any one can help ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe The Port That needed Open via Orbot is used By Another App ...Use 
SockStat to check

Which services are listening on The port And you need to 
disable all apps listening on Orbots Port

also you can change Orbots port to different ... Hope This Help You